# Cannot add some YouTube videos to offline mode

Tags: youtube, offline

I'm trying to add videos to offline mode, but it added only one video successfully. For any other videos I try, it says,

> Offline Unavailable. Sorry, this video can't be taken offline.

What should I do?

Comment: Not all videos are available for offline watch

Comment: It would be helpful if you can mention some videos that you can't add to offline mode.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing you can do, since it seems not all videos can be taken offline. From [an article on Techniqued](http://www.nirmaltv.com/2014/12/12/download-youtube-videos-on-android/),

> **Note:** Remember not all videos can be taken offline and some videos might show this error "Sorry, this video can’t be taken offline" message. YouTube does not clearly mention what is the criteria for videos to be available offline. So in case you encounter this issue, you will not be able to view the video offline.

Based on research, there is a possibility that videos with copyrighted content (e.g. Vevo) can't be taken offline. [A commenter wrote](http://www.igyaan.in/92418/youtube-buffer-free/),

> Most of the videos I tried, are giving error, ‘This video can’t be taken offline.’
> Most of them are from vevo, however I tried for an old hindi song and that one worked.

Or, it might be related to [YouTube Music Key](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6060860?hl=en&ref_topic=6060820).

> ## Availability
>
> You must be a [Music Key](https://support.google.com/youtube/topic/6060820) subscriber to take music videos offline.

Other than that, there's almost no clue.

Answer (score 1):

This is intentional. Some videos are opted-out of the option to download the video, for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to watch video later you can **Download** it.
There are many sites available from which you can download youtube videos. e.g [9xBuddy](http://www.9xbuddy.com) SaveFrom and many more.

*Example (From 9xBuddy)*

- Go to Video which you want to download.
- Add '9x' in beginning of url e.g (www.youtube.com/watch?v=abc) >>> (9xyoutube.com/watch?v=abc)
- Download it.

P.S:

### *Disclaimer : Downloading YouTube Videos without authors permission is Illegal . Do it on your own risk*

**Alternatives**
Try to find video via other sources.
e.g: Tubidy - (Video Search Engine).

Torrent

etc.

Comment: Just remember that this is against the Youtube EULA, and would violate the terms of use, meaning you're being a bad E-Person ;-)

Comment: Dear , I am not saying to use it for every video.Just for videos that one is unable to view offline.

Comment: [Youtube EULA](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms). Section 4C (access videos from valid players only), 5B/C (cannot download videos unless the author has given permission). Whether for one or many, if the author does not want it downloaded, you're violating the terms