# Offline YouTube feature suddenly gone

Tags: youtube, offline

Till yesterday noon I was using this offline option, but from yesterday night I can't get the offline option. My YouTube app is built-in app, will that make any difference?

I even tried re-installation of the app, but I still didn't get it. Help me to get my offline option back.

I found that my YouTube was updated on 18th September 2015. But since I used the offline option since yesterday (21st September 2015), I think the version is not the problem.

Comment: What is your device and where do you live? Note that YouTube offline video is only available in some countries. Also, [not all videos support it](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/102372/cannot-add-some-youtube-videos-to-offline-mode). If this is not the issue, please explain more clearly: does this happen to all videos?

Comment: Am using samsung galaxy grand max... and till yesterday i used offline option. But from yesterday night i can.t access that option.. i think its the same for all here... has youtube withdraw that option in updated versio or something like that

Comment: I'm in India. It wasn't gone for me until today(Feb 11 2016). Deleted my 3GB worth of offline videos in a country where people barely know what hi-speed internet feels like

Answer (score -2):

offline mode is for youtube red users now

Comment: While it's true that YouTube Red provides offline mode, it's currently exclusive for US. I'm still not sure about other countries (e.g. India, Indonesia), because of the reason these countries had this feature in the first place (i.e. slow connection)...

Comment: Now that I'm currently in Indonesia, I can ensure that this answer is wrong: offline mode is still available in some countries, without needing YouTube Red.

Comment: @AndrewT. I'm in Kenya and can also attest to that statement being wrong. I can access the offline YouTube video feature at the moment.